# Error boot Linux after using Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10.

But after using Windows and then when I restart for boot into Linux, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I tried to fix this issue by executing this command on the command line"

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda7
```

How I can fix this issue, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To repair the file system in its current state run the commands suggested in the preceding error message until you find one that works:

1. `e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sda7`
2. `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda7`

If neither works please edit your question to explain what you did and what happened exactly.

If either command works and if this error keeps reoccurring each time after you boot Windows I suggest you [open a new question](/questions/ask) about it.